# Changing pandas dataframe by reference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large DataFrames that I don't want to make copies of, but want to apply the same change to. How can I do this properly? For example, this is similar to what I want to do, but on a smaller scale. This only creates the temporary variable df that gives the result of each DataFrame, but I want both DataFrames to be themselves changed:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,5,7]})
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df = df[df['a'] < 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do `query` with `inplace`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,5,7]})
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df.query('a<3',inplace=True)

df1
   a
0  1
1  2
df2
   a
0  0
1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is the best solution, but should do the job.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,5,7]})
dfs = [df1, df2]
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    dfs[i] = df[df['a'] < 3]


dfs[0]

   a
0  1
1  2
```